# How to start a new rails project without overhead of actioncable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I know most of the rails experts know the answer to this simple question but since not every new rails app is going to be a chat application or would even need a redis/websockets sitting in there, how to create a new rails project without actioncable?

`$ rails new <project name> --option`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should be `rails new --skip-action-cable`

Found via `rails new --help`